# XML namespace in appy-templates

Tags: xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

Below is input XML.

```
     <ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
         <Problem>
          <Ticket>
            <UrgencyCode>3</UrgencyCode>
            <ImpactCode>2</ImpactCode>
          </Ticket>
        </Problem>
     </ServiceIncident>
```

And  iam using the below xsl.My problem is i need to use the prefix r2 and root element serviceincident in every x- path expression so i applied template match so that there is no repetetion ot this tag but iam not getting output if iam applying template match.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:r2="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="r2:ServiceIncident"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r2:ServiceIncident">
        <custom2>
            <xsl:value-of select="r2:ServiceIncident/r2:Problem/r2:Ticket/r2:ImpactCode"/>
        </custom2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside of the template you need to use a path relative to the matched node so

```
   <xsl:template match="r2:ServiceIncident">
         <custom2>
 <xsl:value-of select="r2:Problem/r2:Ticket/r2:ImpactCode"/>
        </custom2>
        </xsl:template>
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: if iam using <xsl:template match="r2:ServiceIncident"> in xsl iam not getting output values.If i remove the prefix r2 and root element in template match and if i use int the x-path expression then iam getting output.

Comment: ok i missed Problem in xml while typing but still if i use Problem in xml also even then iam not getting output.

Comment: With edited input sample the XSLT inside the template now needs to be `<xsl:value-of select="r2:Problem/r2:Ticket/r2:ImpactCode"/>`.